# Flag rows with all values of specific columns are null for a specific condition

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with columns ReferenceID, ReferenceType,  Amount,  itemcode , and flag. I need to set flag when all the Amount and itemcode values are null for a particular ReferenceType within each Reference ID.

Table values looks like this. Values are dynamic and when condition is satisfied, need to update flag

```
ReferenceID  | ReferenceType | Amount | itemcode | flag |

4000 | X006| 250 | cx      |   | (flag 0)
4000 | X003| 260 | NULL         |    | (flag 0)
4000 | X003| NULL    | NULL    |   | (flag 0)
4001 | X002 | NULL   | NULL     |   | (flag 1)
4001 | X002 | NULL   | NULL     |    | (flag 1)
4001 | X003 | 600 | NULL      |   |  (flag 0)
4001 | X003 | 500 | 500 |  | (flag 0)
4002 | X003 | NULL   |  NULL   |     | (flag 1)
4002 | X003| NULL    | NULL    |     | (flag 1)
```

For all rows of X002  in ReferenceID 4001, all values of amount and item code are null so flag need to be 1.
For X003 in 4002 also flag need to be set. (X003 in 4000 has got not null values as well, so flag need to be 0)

Please help me on this as I couldn't find a solution for this.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking here, but it looks like what you want is something like `UPDATE [YourTableName] SET [flag] = 1 WHERE ReferenceID=4001 AND ReferenceType='X002' AND Amount IS NULL AND itemcode IS NULL`. Where are you currently getting stuck?

Comment: Values are dynamic. When condition are satisfied, flag need to be updated. Values given in table are examples.

Answer (score 0):

Let's repeat the task in words that can be translated to T-SQL:

For a record in your table where there is a record in your table with the same ReferenceID and ReferenceType with not both Amount and itemcode empty, reset the flag to 0, otherwise set the flag to 1. In SQL, this reads:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET flag =
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM YourTable
                 WHERE ReferenceID = t.ReferenceID
                   AND ReferenceType = t.ReferenceType 
                   AND NOT (Amount IS NULL AND itemcode IS NULL))
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END
FROM YourTable t
```